What will be the equation as a function of x for this graph?
This is the graph:

And I want to find what equation can plot this graph.
I believe somehow trigonometric functions and fourier transform can do it. But don't know how.

This looks like exponential decay, where your x-axis is time $t$, for a repeating, inverting process. If we define the rate of exponential decay $k$, and the duration of each repetition $T$, and then use the floor and modulo functions to construct the repetitive and inverting aspects, we can have:
Inversion every repetition time: $(-1)^{\lfloor{\frac{t}{T}}\rfloor}$
Fixed decay every repetition time: $e^{-k*(t \mod{T})}$
Together, $y=(-1)^{\lfloor{\frac{t}{T}}\rfloor}e^{-k*(t \mod{T})}$
Choosing values like $T=1, k=4, t \in [0,4]$ will give a picture much like yours.


Here is a closed form solution (we assume that the period is $T=1$) :
$$y=e^{-a (x-\lfloor x \rfloor)}\operatorname{sign}(\sin(\pi x))$$
where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is for the greatest integer less or equal to $x$ (drawn in blue on the figure below) ; as a consequence $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the fractional part of $x$ with values in $[0,1)$. $a$ is an adjustable parameter (we have taken $a=2$ in the figure below).

Remark : for an adjustable period $T$, just take :
$$y=e^{-a (x/T-\lfloor x/T \rfloor)}\operatorname{sign}(\sin(\pi x/T))$$

Any comment ?...
